# tracking embeded youtube videos views

Tags: iframe, youtube, google-analytics

I have embeded some youtube videos in my website. I want to track the views of each videos with google analytics, but I cannot catch any onClick event because the videos are embeded in using iFrame. How can I track the views of youtube videos that is embeded in my webpage using iFrame ?

Answer (score 2):

I've been using YouTube's API to track plays as events in Google Analytics. It's the same format in [iFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events) and javascript. Look at the iFrame API if you want to track other functions. This is where I originally got the [event tracking information](http://www.bluefountainmedia.com/blog/track-youtube-player-events-google-analytics/).

You'll have to change the **videoID** below:

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    var player;

    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'fYmrMt01S1U',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        /// event.target.playVideo(); 
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play',
            player.getVideoUrl()]);
        }
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Paused',
            player.getVideoUrl()]);
        }
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Watch to End',
            player.getVideoUrl()]);
        }
    }
    // ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for the reply, I implemented the above, but at the end the video loads/plays very slowly like frame by frame. Ho do I resolve it ? any Idea ? did you also face the same problem ?

Comment: I haven't had any problems, but I do get loading problems on YouTube often. It could be that you have it set to load in HD?

Comment: Is there a way to make this work for a video that is opened in a fancy box like this: <a class="fancyboxvideo" href="video.html" data-fancybox-type="iframe"> ?