# track an embedded youtube video in with google analytics

Tags: google-chrome, google-analytics, youtube-api

I was trying to figure out the simplest way to check how many users watch an embedded youtube video. Would the following work fine?

```
$('.video').click(function(){
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'Video Views', 'Play', 'The Perfect Belgian Serve']);

    });
```

.video is a class given to the iframe tag.

Just found this plug-in:

```
<div class="ytvid">ylLzyHk54Z0</div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ytiframetracker.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(function ($) {
    $.ytiframetracker({
      track: function (action, label, value) { // track callback
        console.log('custom tracking', action, label, value);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ytiframetracker/wiki/Examples

Could somebody explain what action, label and value are there for?

Comment: <iframe class="video" width="882" height="496" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/c9f7w8EB5Os?wmode=opaque&amp;rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: This given answer could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602983/tracking-embeded-youtube-videos-views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of relying on Google Analytics and custom events/tracking, you could use the YouTube Analytics API: http://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics

That assumes that the video in question belongs to your own account, though, since you can't use YouTube Analytics for videos in arbitrary accounts.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that plugin uses Event tracking, and you’ll find plenty of information here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#Anatomy

Comment: Hi there, thanks but how does this code refer to the actual video that I need to track? I've just red what action, label and value are, is there a way of using the video ID somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the code in your html, and replace Enter your GA Tracking ID with your tracking id

```html
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'Enter your GA Tracking ID', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['instamojo.com'] );
  ga('send', 'pageview');

 
 
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.id = 'iframe-demo';
  tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('youTubePlayer', {
  events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
  }
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
 
  }
  function changeBorderColor(playerStatus) {
    
    var color;
    if (playerStatus == -1) {
      color = "#37474F"; 
    } else if (playerStatus == 0) {
      color = "#FFFF00"; 
    } else if (playerStatus == 1) {
  
      color = "#33691E"; 
   ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play-videoname', 'videoname');  
 
   
    } else if (playerStatus == 2) {
 
      color = "#DD2C00"; 
    ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'Pause-videoname', 'videoname');  
 
    } else if (playerStatus == 3) { 
      color = "#AA00FF"; 
    } else if (playerStatus == 5) {
      color = "#FF6DOO"; 
    }
    if (color) {
      document.getElementById('youTubePlayer').style.borderColor = color;
    }
  }
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    changeBorderColor(event.data);
  }
  
 </script>
```